# get value from different HTML elements that have the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering how to get value from different HTML elements that have the same class? Taken out of it's context this might look strange but there's a reason the code looks like this.

For example, the HTML code might look something like this:

```js
 $('.b').each(function () {
    alert('dfd');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <textarea class="a b">Text1</textarea>
    <textarea class="a b">Text2</textarea>
    <textarea class="a b">Text3</textarea>
    
    <div class="b c">...</div>
    <div class="b c">...</div>
    <div class="b c">...</div>
```

The alert will execute 6 times as there is a total of 6 elements using class "`b`". My question is, is it possible to only alert the values from the textareas and skip the divs? A direct path like "`textarea .b`".

Comment: used to this $('textarea.b').each

Comment: Try `$('textarea.b')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to this

`$('.b')` into this `$('textarea.b')`

```
$('textarea.b').each(function () {
    alert('dfd');
    });
```

if you are using this `$('.b')` means all `class` `.b`

if you  are using this `$('textarea.b')` means all `textarea` **with** `class` `.b`

Comment: Thx, must have missed a space or something.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the selector `textarea.b` (no space) should work fine!

Comment: Damn early mornings. Thxs

Answer (score 0):

Add `textarea` to the selector

```
$('textarea.b').each(function () {
    alert('dfd');
    });
```

Given your code, you can also use this selector :

```
$('.a.b').each(function () {
    alert('dfd');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the `textarea.b` as following and access the value:

```
$('textarea.b').each(function(index, txtArea){
        //accecc the contexted textarea either using $(this) or     
        //$(txtArea)
        var val = $(this).val();
        alert('textarea-'+index+': '+ val)
})
```

Check the fiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/9xmtv3pk/